# OpenSearch: Aggregate data per document

Tags: elasticsearch, opensearch

I am wondering if the following is possible. I want to be able aggregate nested data within a document and then filter by the aggregated data.

So if we have

```
PUT warehouse/
{
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "inventory": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "equipment": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "shopId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "profile": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

and then put data

```
PUT warehouse/_doc/1
{
  "profile": {
    "name": "Place1"
  },
  "inventory": [
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 1000.00, "shopId":"1"},
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 200.00, "shopId":"2"},
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 1.0, "shopId":"4"}
  ]
}
```

etc

I need to do filter by shopIds, say shopId 1 and shopId 2. Then aggregate that data per document, so for document above the average guitar price for shopId1 and shopId2 is 150.

I then want to only return documents and values that meed a criteria, so I say shopId1 + shopId2 AND average price >130.

I am able to get some aggregation working but it is aggregation across all the documents returned, not per document.

The following gives me the average price across all documents that match the search

```
GET warehouse/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "inventory",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "inventory": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "inventory"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "priceAgg": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "avg_price": {
              "avg": {
                "field": "inventory.price"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Result:

```
"aggregations" : {
    "inventory" : {
      "doc_count" : 9,
      "priceAgg" : {
        "doc_count" : 3,
        "avg_price" : {
          "value" : 2000.0
        }
      }
    }
```

But what I need is the price for the criteria per document

Newer versions of ElasticSearch have runtime mapping but this is not available in OpenSearch

Another possible option might be to redesign the search document but I still don't see how the combined values per shopId can be generated and filtered on

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [sub-aggs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations.html#run-sub-aggs) inside of nested aggs.

```
PUT test_warehouse/
{
  "mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "inventory": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "equipment": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "shopId": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    },
    "profile": {
      "properties": {
        "name": {
          "type": "keyword"
        }
      }
    }
  }
  }
}
```

---

```
PUT test_warehouse/_doc/1?refresh
{
  "profile": {
    "name": "Place1"
  },
  "inventory": [
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 1000.00, "shopId":"1"},
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 200.00, "shopId":"2"},
    {"equipment":"guitar", "price": 1.0, "shopId":"4"},
    {"equipment":"clarinet", "price": 355, "shopId":"2"}
  ]
}
```

---

```
GET test_warehouse/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "inventory": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "inventory"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "priceAgg": {
          "filter": {
            "bool": {
              "should": [
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "1"
                  }
                },
                {
                  "term": {
                    "inventory.shopId": "2"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "NAME": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "inventory.equipment"
              },
              "aggs": {
                "NAME": {
                  "avg": {
                    "field": "inventory.price"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

## The output:

```
{
  "took": 2,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": {
      "value": 1,
      "relation": "eq"
    },
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "inventory": {
      "doc_count": 4,
      "priceAgg": {
        "doc_count": 3,
        "NAME": {
          "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
          "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
          "buckets": [
            {
              "key": "guitar",
              "doc_count": 2,
              "NAME": {
                "value": 600
              }
            },
            {
              "key": "clarinet",
              "doc_count": 1,
              "NAME": {
                "value": 355
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Musab, thanks for the reply, yes that will work and give the values like you have but what I ultimately need is a way to filter the documents by these results. So in your example there is a guitar bucket with a value. Is it possible to then first the document which only have a guitar value greater than say 500?

Comment: yes it's possible. Use the range query with aggs.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html

Comment: To filter the buckets uses the aggregates data I meant? Not an initial query

Comment: hmm, bucket_selector aggregation can help..
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html